# Concatenating a string from an array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a full names that have been read into arrays. I am trying to create a file using only the last name; the last name might have white spaces that should be replaced by underscores. My thought is to create a string of the file name and then create the file. I have already taken care of the cases with only one last name. I am having trouble with the last names with white spaces. This is what I have so far:

```
if [ "${#name_arr[@]}" -eq 2 ]; then
    for i in "${name_arr[@]:1}";do  # :1 because first element is their first name
        last_name=$i
    done
    echo $last_name
else
    for i in "${name_arr[@]:1}";do
        last_name=${last_name}_${i}
    done
    echo $last_name
fi
```

The output of this concatenates all of the names with underscores. So instead of:

```
Doe
Austen
Vaughn_Williams
Doe
```

It is echoing:

```
Doe
Austen
Austen_Vaughn_Williams
Doe
```

Comment: Do you mean `if [ "${#name_arr[@]}" -eq 2 ]` (note the `#`)?

Comment: @tripleee yes, sorry, that was a typo. Just fixed.

Comment: The actual output would be `_Vaughn_Williams` and not `Austen_Vaughn_Williams`. It will start with an '_' based on your code. Are you sure you are posting the correct output?

Comment: Yes, that is what my output is showing. No underscore before. Edit: If I change the variable for last name to `long_last_name`, then it does output `_Vaughn_Williams`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need loops, or nor do you need to check the length of the list. Just join all but the first element with a space to get the last name.

```
last_name=${name_arr[*]:1}  # Assuming the default value of IFS
last_name=${last_name// /_}
```

At the cost of a fork, you can do this in one line.

```
last_name=$(IFS='_'; echo "${name_arr[*]:1}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
if [ "${#name_arr[@]}" -eq 2 ]; then
    for i in "${name_arr[@]:1}";do  # :1 because first element is their first name
        last_name=$i
    done
    echo $last_name
else
    last_name=${name_arr[1]}
    for i in "${name_arr[@]:2}";do
        last_name=${last_name}_${i}
    done
    echo $last_name
fi
```

First, take the 2nd element of the name_arr in the last_name, and add the remaining elements of the array in to the last_name variable with a loop